# How to add while_list by api aci_gap_configure_whitelist

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32

I'm implementing source code for module BLE IDB05A1 on STM32L496

My devices is BLE peripheral
I added device is connected on whilelist by api: aci_gap_configure_whitelist()
Set discovery by api: aci_gap_set_discoverable() with avdFilterPolicy = WHITE_LIST_FOR_ONLY_CONN

#### define WHITE_LIST_FOR_ONLY_CONN    (0x02)  /**< Process scan requests from all devices and only connection requests from devices that are in the White List */

My goal is all phone can connect to my device and only phone on whileList can conncet to my device.

my source code as below:
- phone connect to my devices -> add phone connected to whilelist -> my device set discovery with policy filer is WHITE_LIST_FOR_ONLY_CONN.

However, phone which connected before can't connect to my device. it only scan.

I suspect can't add phone to whileList. So this issue happend

Comment: Which phone are you using? Does it have random resolvable address?

Comment: I use android phone (galaxy note 8). Address of my phone is not change

Comment: Which address type is it using then, static random or public? I thought all Android devices use random resolvable address, which updates every 15 minutes.

Comment: yes. address is changed. yesterday, address is 74-7E-85-8E-1F-94. However today, it is changed to 69-0B-7F-F7-E9-C1